# Как преобразовать DataFrameGroupBy object в dataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

Есть непустой датафрейм без Nan'ов. Моя задача состоит в следующем:

1. датафрейм необходимо сгруппировать по значениям одного столбца(значения столбца -- строки, они повторяются)
   имеем: df.groupby('feature')
2. далее необходимо посчитать средние значения числовых столбцов, которые получаются в результате группировки
   получаем: df.groupby('feature').mean().T (транспонирование для удобства)
3. есть нюанс! средние значения нужно посчитать исключительно у столбцов типа int(очевидно, в сгруппированном df есть ещё и столбцы с float

Как это реализовать?
Были попытки сделать это через .select_dtypes(include = ['int64']) и пр, но они не увенчались успехом по причине 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'блаблабла'

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных (в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл) и __то, что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: То есть, `df.groupby('feature')["column_with_ints"].mean()` вы уже попробовали?

Comment: @strawdog, похоже автор вопроса из той категории спрашивающих, которые предпочитают подождать неопределенное время пока не придет чтец мыслей и ответит на мысли автора. А уточнять вопросы - это удел слабаков! :-D

Comment: колонок, где есть значения int может быть очень много.
есть, конечно, вариант, когда можно узнать все атрибуты, через describe() понять где какой тип данных и через цикл посчитать среднее только в тех столбцах, где тип данных int
Но это очень громоздко и мне стало интересно, можно ли это сделать с помощью agg(), например

Comment: Скорее всего можно, но никто не будет тратить своё время на вариант решения, который с большой вероятностью вам не подойдёт, потому что при работе с Pandas важны детали. Не имея воспроизводимого примера данных и ожидаемого результата, в 70-80% случаев время будет потрачено впустую. Вероятность получения качественного ответа напрямую зависит от качества вопроса)